# Combine data of two tables into one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables that are somewhat similar and both contain columns like this, among others

```
+-----------+----------+
| Name      | ID       |
+-----------+----------+
| Name1     | 1        |
| Name2     | 2        |
| Name3     | 3        |
+-----------+----------+
```

I want a result with one column containing all entries of both tables, so assuming `Table1` has 50 records and `Table2` has 100, I want a result of 150 records. So I basically want to append the results of `Table2` onto the results of `Table1`.

How do I achieve this? DB is MSSQL

Comment: You want `UNION ALL`!

Comment: to add to @jarlh comment also consider to normalize and use a single table with maybe a type based table.. As it is not clear why the tables (with the same columns) are separated in the first place..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I'm reading data from an event management software, one table is projects, the other is so called jobs, which are basically subprojects. they are seperated to enable a 1*n relationship. Also, I don't develop the database, people with a lot more experience do that. I'm fairly certain it's normalized.

Comment: *"I'm fairly certain it's normalized."* ..  well thats debatable and also matter of taste  consider the tables  `event: id(event_type, name)  event_type(id, name)`  where `event_type(name)` can be `project/job`  .. *" I'm reading data from an event management software"* But never mind mine normalisation comment it's out of your power when using third party software..

Comment: @RaymondNijland the suggestion sounds good, but I'm not sure how much the other fields differentiate. Also a job can't exist on it's own, it's always a "child" of a project. I only look at those two columns anyway, because they're the only ones interesting to me, lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `UNION ALL` as

```
SELECT Col1, Col2
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT Col1, Col2
FROM Table2;
```

Answer (score 3):

You will likely want the UNION or UNION ALL command.

See here for the W3 Schools Demo: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_union.asp

For your Example:

```
SELECT Name, ID
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT Name, ID
FROM Table2
Order By Name
```

Don't forget about the 'Order By!'